# Menu item navigating to localhost rather than the home page

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a navigation bar on my website with a menu item the home page. When I click on it, it takes me to the localhost main page but not the home page of the website.

```
<div class="top-navigation-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">POPULAR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FEATURED</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="/submit">SUBMIT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For the home page, I am using the default route:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

(I'm using the CakePHP framework.)

I am using MAMP and I believe it has something to do with MAMP but not CakePHP or my code.

Comment: what is your home page url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your link (`<a href="/">HOME</a>`) to `<?php echo $this->Html->link('Home', '/'); ?>`.

A link that points to `'/'` will always link to the root of the web server. Using Cake's HtmlHelper's `link()` method, `'/'` will resolve to the root of the app instead of the root of the web server and output the `<a>` tag you need.